# Can't answer questions, not even my own: Please note, I can still post questions, but not answers

Tags: support, stack-overflow, answers, post-ban

Since I joined Stack Overflow I have never been able to post answers to any questions, not even my own questions. Is there something I should do in order to be allowed to do this?

Every time I try, I get this error message:

> We are no longer accepting answers from this account. See this meta post to learn more.

I do use Stack Overflow at work sometimes, but even when I use it at home I get the same error message.

Comment: If this is since the very beginning, are you on a network with more SO users?

Comment: I flagged this as a dup too, but I'm kicking myself for being too hasty after re-reading the first sentence of the post.  Might not be a dup actually.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Well, I'm thinking the following might be the case (from the dupe): *"when you browse from a shared computer or from work location that give the same IP address to many end users it's enough that one get banned and all others are "banned" as well. To rectify this, just browse from a different location"*

Comment: @Bart fair point, but that section is at the very bottom after all of the discussion about bad posts.  I guess my point was trying to hold off closing long enough to confirm that it is a shared IP problem for him.

Comment: @psubsee2003 If he's been banned since he joined SO then how did he managed to ask the six questions on his profile?

Comment: @Servy: "...I couldn't post ***answers*** to any questions..."

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby Ah, my mistake.  Answer bans are so rare.

Comment: I have the same problem, :( anyone knows the answer?

Comment: @Won't I am having this problem too can you help. I want to write this. This code use template. I can't do if because the program gives 102 error

why ??

#include<iostream.h>
#include<string.h>
template <class BX>
class stack
{
private:
    int Top;
    int size;
    BX *S;
public:
    stack(int RX=300):size(RX),S(NULL),Top(0)
    {
        Top=size=0;
        S=new char[size=RX];
    }

    ~stack(){

        if(S)delete []S;
            S=NULL;
            Top=size=0;
    }
int empty()const
{
    return this->Top==0;
}

int full()const
{
return Top==size;
}

void push(char n='a')
{

Comment: I don't know why this is marked as duplicate but my question is different from what it is marked as duplicate of. I can post questions, not answers, not even to my own questions and this can't be a ban, cause I was never able too, yes I use S/O at work **sometimes** but even when I use it at home it does same thing

Comment: If you get the message you have put into your question here, it is a dupe. However, I am not sure if an IP-based post-ban carries over to your home location as well. It might well be that that's the case. I.e. a ban because of your work IP still holds at home. Though a mod/dev will have to confirm that.